# How do I give a user permission to install Report Builder from Report Manager? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2008

By default, users do not see the "Report Builder" button on the Report Manager toolbar in SQL Server 2008 (R1).  How do I give the user permission to use the Report Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Try graning Manage Reports

Answer (score 0):

There is a role for this on the security tab in Report manager.  Do a new role assignment or add the Report Builder role to an existing role assignment.  Additionally you may need to add them to the site security section as a System User.

```
Home Folder Security:
http:/localhost/reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab

Site Security:
http:/localhost/reports/Pages/Settings.aspx?SelectedSubTabId=SecurityLinkID
```